# How can I evaluate an expression string containing variables?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, algebra, expression-evaluation

In Unity I'm trying to make it so you enter an expression and then it outputs a value but I want to use variables like:

```
x = 10
"x + x * 10"
```

^
outputs `200`

Comment: I don't understand your "equation".

Comment: That's an "expression" not an "equation" and you'd be "evaluating" not "solving" it.  Do you have something that evaluates text _without_ variables (e.g. `"10 + 10 * 10"`)?

Comment: Have a look at `DataTable` class `Compute` method: create `DataTable` instance, add *columns* with variable names - `x` in your case, add *row* with variable values - `10` in your case and `Compute` the formula - `x + x * 10`

Comment: Why do you expect 200 as output value? I would expect 110.

Comment: @Elec1 Evidently `+` has the same or greater precedence than `*`.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a Mathematical expression evaluator. This is essentially an algorithm to  tokenize your input string and then evaluate every single token.
Just search for "Mathematical expression evaluator in c# " and you'll find what you need.Because this is a quite large project on its own, it  might make sense to use a library for that.
Here are some libraries:

[Math-Expression-evaluator](https://github.com/Giorgi/Math-ExpressionEvaluator)

[Matheval](https://github.com/matheval/expression-evaluator-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

If you feel more adventurous you could even write your own évaluator using a parser library. This will allow specific behaviors if needed. Some libraries are :

- [sprache](https://github.com/sprache/Sprache)
- [eto.parse](https://github.com/picoe/Eto.Parse)
- [csly](https://github.com/b3b00/csly)
- [superpower](https://github.com/datalust/superpower)